# how to order List<T> through string child element?

Tags: c#, list, ribbon, cpu-word

I must order a list according to a string contained in each element of the list.

I have a ribbonDropDown element which contains a list of ribbonDropDownItem. Each of those item contains a string from which I want to reorder the item position in the ribbonDropDown alphabatically.
I think my problem can be solve just by considering I have a List of object which contain a string field.

I tried this :

```
List<myObject> myList = aList;
myList.OrderBy(i => i.Name, StringComparer.Ordinal);
```

and also

```
myList.OrderBy(i => i.Name);
```

I expect the result to be order from a->z or z->a depending on the method I use (OrderBy or OrderBy descening).
For now my result is the same order of my list before the operation.

Is it possible to use this method for that or should I use something else ?
I'd like not to use a for loop.

Comment: Think of `OrderBy` as being like `string.Replace`. It doesn't change the original string - it creates a new one. Calling `OrderBy` doesn't change the list at all. It creates a new `IEnumerable<T>` which contains the same elements as the original list, but in a different order.

Comment: `myList.Sort((x, y) => string.CompareOrdinal(x.Name, y.Name));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reassign the return of the `.OrderBy()` to the original list.

```
myList = myList.OrderBy(i => i.Name).ToList();
```

`.OrderBy()` does not change the existing list, it returns the input list with the modifications as a new `IEnumerable<>`.